# My spring boot app quits without error as soon as it loads

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bazel

I am converting a maven spring boot app into a bazel based app. I finally got it compile correctly, but as soon as I run it, it just quits. The server doesn't start but it prints the sprint boot start up message.

I think it has to do with spring not being able to find a servlet, but I am very new to java so I don't know where to look.

I am not able to get any usable info from the JVM as to why it just quits. Is there a way I can increase spring's logging verbosity?

Here's my Application.java

```
package com.example.abc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AbcClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(AbcClient.class, args);
    }
}
```

My WORKSPACE file

```
maven_jar(
    name = "org_springframework_spring_core",
    artifact = "org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "org_springframework_spring_beans",
    artifact = "org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "org_springframework_spring_context",
    artifact = "org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "org_springframework_spring_aop",
    artifact = "org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "org_springframework_spring_expression",
    artifact = "org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.1.RELEASE"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "org_springframework_boot_spring_boot",
    artifact = "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_autoconfigure",
    artifact = "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_aop",
    artifact = "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_web",
    artifact = "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_test",
    artifact = "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "org_apache_tomcat_embed_tomcat_embed_core",
    artifact = "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.12"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "org_apache_tomcat_embed_tomcat_embed_jasper",
    artifact = "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:jar:9.0.12"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "org_springframework_boot",
    artifact = "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "javax_servlet_jstl",
    artifact = "javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "javax_servlet_javax_servlet_api",
    artifact = "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.1"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "commons_logging_commons_logging",
    artifact = "commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "javax_servlet_jsp_javax_servlet_jsp_api",
    artifact = "javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.3"
)
```

and my BUILD file

```
java_binary(
    name = "AbcClient",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/com/example/abc/*.java"]),
    deps = [
        "@org_springframework_spring_core//jar",
        "@org_springframework_spring_beans//jar",
        "@org_springframework_spring_aop//jar",
        "@org_springframework_spring_expression//jar",
        "@org_springframework_boot_spring_boot//jar",
        "@org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_autoconfigure//jar",
        "@org_springframework_spring_context//jar",
        "@org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_aop//jar",
        "@org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_web//jar",
        "@org_apache_tomcat_embed_tomcat_embed_core//jar",
        "@org_apache_tomcat_embed_tomcat_embed_jasper//jar",
        "@javax_servlet_jstl//jar",
        "@javax_servlet_javax_servlet_api//jar",
        "@javax_servlet_jsp_javax_servlet_jsp_api//jar",
        "@commons_logging_commons_logging//jar",
    ],
    resources = glob([
        "src/main/java/resources/*",
        "src/main/java/webapp/resources/**"
    ])
)
```

Comment: Can you share the logs?

Answer (score 2):

It should be enough to have `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency, this by default includes Tomcat. You might be missing the dependencies when running the application e.g. see that `SpringBootServletInitializer` is present and running.

Take a look at [bazel-springboot-rule](https://github.com/salesforce/bazel-springboot-rule) project and [springboot.bzl
 Packager](https://github.com/salesforce/bazel-springboot-rule/blob/master/tools/springboot/springboot.bzl) which package Spring Boot application as runnable JAR using Bazel (in similar way it's done by Maven and Gradle). It's more or less:

```
load("//tools/springboot:springboot.bzl",
    "springboot",
    "add_boot_web_starter"
)

add_boot_web_starter(app_deps)

springboot(
    name = "spring-boot-sample",
    boot_app_class = "com.main.Application",
    deps = app_deps
)
```

Comment: I'd like to figure out how to use bazel without bazel-springboot-rule. I want a config that I understand fully, since my reason for moving to bazel is having more control over what dependencies I include into my app. Where do I initialize SpringBootServletInitializer? I thought that was only necessary if I were running my app on an external tomcat. I want to go the embedded route with this.

Comment: @Ananth Spring Boot uses classpath scanning heavily to enable feature. If a Servlet Container classes are on the classpath then it should be started by `SpringBootServletInitializer`. You are not supposed to touch the Spring Boot glue code in your application. Most likely your runtime classpath or `MANIFEST.MF` file is broken compare this with Maven setup from [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/)